# How to amend gridview cell value with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have create a gridview as following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" CellPadding="1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField headertext="ColumnA">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:label id="ColumnA" Text='<%#Eval("ColumnA")%>' runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

How I can add a click event (on the label) and change the value of the cell (that is clicked) in javascript? I've tried various ways using jquery but none of them are working properly, hopefully you can help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you've tried and what has gone wrong? What jQuery selectors have you used?

Comment: The asp.net data table does not generate unique id for each row, so I cannot change the value by just jquery's selector , so you have some idea how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting some [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx) to your label and applying a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in jQuery. Then you can just access the contents of the label to produce a new value without any need for unique row ID.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server"  // DataSource="<%# DataItems %>" 
    CellPadding="1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="ColumnA">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label CssClass="ColumnA" Text='<%#Eval("ColumnA")%>' runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script>
    $("#Grid1 .ColumnA").click(function () {
        var content = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(content + " Changed");
    });
</script>
```

If you have a need then you can also store some additional (like unique id) information in [data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) :

```
 <asp:label data-id='<%#Eval("UniqueIdDataForClickEvent")%>' CssClass="ColumnA" Text='We have no actual data' runat="server"/>

...

<script>
    $("#Grid1 .ColumnA").click(function () {
        var content = $(this).data("id");
        $(this).html("We had unique id " + content);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Engene how to make the changed made by jQuery available in c# code?